# Is there a file limit?

Tags: hacknet

I have been downloading any and all of the important files that I find, and I haven't run into any problems yet. I know that there is a RAM limit, but is there a limit to the amount of files you can have, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there's not. The only limit is your hard drive space IRL, since each file you get increases the size of the game's save file, assuming that you don't delete it on the computer you got it from.

Note that the game's save file is currently stored in `xml` format, so you can open it and see how everything is stored. I wouldn't recommend downloading multiple copies of a large file, as your save file will likely increase by that size for each file.